# How to make a "circular" array where 1 is as close to 360 as 359?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am working with some data on the orientation of clasts in a sedimentary ridge. I have measured the compass direction the clasts dip in, and I have put the data in numpy arrays. The problem is that the arrays now are linear. How can I tell Python that when I do statistical analysis, 357 and 3 has the same distance to 360? Is it possible to make a circular array?

Comment: You could use `min((a1-a2)%360, (a1-a2)%360)`. This will give the smallest number of degrees around the circle, clockwise or counterclockwise. Another option is to convert the angles to points on the unit circle `(cos(a1), sin(a1))` and `(cos(a2), sin(a2))`, then find the Euclidean distance between those points.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say how to help you without a MWE, but I can point out that modulo (%) is usually how circular quantities are dealt with.

```
1-360           # -359
360-359         # 1
(1-360) % 360   # 1
(360-359) % 360 # 1

359-360         # -1
360-1           # 359
(359-360) % 360 # 359
(360-1) % 360   # 359
```

If direction doesn't matter, you can find the minimum angular difference with:

```
def diff(a, b, turn=360): return min( ((a-b) % turn) , ((b-a) % turn) )
```